# react does not call useState

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

Background:

I followed [this tutorial](https://tania.dev/crud-app-in-react-with-hooks/) and built a working CRUD app using React hooks.
Starting with the code in the tutorial I want to factor the state components out of each view and into a single class.  My reason for doing this is to create a reusable, statically typed viewmodel object.

Problem:

In AddUserForm.tsx I am handling input changes in the function `handleInputChange`.  I am stepping through the code using VS Code debugger and I get this strange behavior:  I put a breakpoint on the line that calls `setCurrentUser` however when I start debugging the breakpoint moves to the line following which is the closing curly brace (all code files are saved to disk and the app builds in TS). For some reason `setCurrentUser` never executes.

AddUserForm.tsx

```
const AddUserForm = (props :any) => {
  
    const vm: UserViewModel = props.vm as UserViewModel;

    const handleInputChange = (event:any) => {
        const vm2 = vm; // closure
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        vm2.setCurrentUser({...vm2.currentUser, [name]:value});  // problem here.  the call to setCurrentUser does not execute.
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            if(! vm.currentUser.name || ! vm.currentUser.username)
                return;

            vm.addUser(vm.currentUser);
            vm.setCurrentUser(new user());

        }}>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value={vm.currentUser.name} onChange={handleInputChange}></input>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" value={vm.currentUser.username} onChange={handleInputChange}></input>
            <button>Add new user</button>
        </form>
    )
}
export default AddUserForm;
```

UserViewModel.tsx

```
export default class UserViewModel
{
    public currentUser: user;
    public users: user[];
    public editing : boolean;
    public setUsers : any;    
    public setCurrentUser : any;
    public setEditing : any;
    
    constructor() {

        const usersData: user[] = [
            {id:1, name:'Tania', username:'floppydiskette'},
            {id:2, name:'Craig', username:'siliconedolon'},
            {id:3, name:'Ben', username:'benisphere'}
          ];
        this.editing = false;
        this.users = usersData;
        this.currentUser = new user();
        this.setCurrentUser = useState<user>(this.currentUser)[1];
        this.setUsers = useState<user[]>(this.users)[1];
        this.setEditing = useState<boolean>(this.editing)[1];
    }

    public addUser: (usr:user) => void = (usr :user) => {
        usr.id = this.users.length + 1;
        this.setUsers([...this.users, usr]);
    };
            
    public editUser: (user:user) => void = (user:user) => {
        this.setEditing(true);
        this.setCurrentUser(user)
    };
            
    public updateUser: (updatedUser:user) => void = (updatedUser:user) => {
        this.setEditing(false);
        this.setUsers(this.users.map((user) => (user.id === updatedUser.id ? updatedUser : user)));
    };
            
    public deleteUser: (id:number) => void = (id:number) => {
        this.setEditing(false);
        this.setUsers(this.users.filter((user) => user.id !== id));
    
    };
}
```

[Before debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gps7k.png)

[image: During debugging]

Comment: `const vm2 = vm; // closure` nope :)

Comment: Your current approach won't work. The problem is that `useState` hook keeps its own state. So `this.setUsers` doesn't mutate original object but replaces entire object with a new one so `this.users` will be unmodified and you basically loose all changes. If you want to create reusable piece of code with hooks check "custom hooks" instead of trying to build an MVVM frankenstein monster. Hooks were designed in FP paradigm they won't play nice with OOP patterns.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thank you.  Onward to vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState is a hook and only works in function components, not class components.

Please refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

On a separate note, your 'viewModel' should only be data and code. It does not have any 'State' and far as React is concerned. Only React components have state in that sense.